# Jackson Register Custom Deserializer To Map From JSON Object to a Collection

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some JSON like this:

```
{
  "version": "1",
  "date": "8/26/16"
  "items": [
    { "row": ["1", "1", "2"]},
    { "row": ["1", "2", "4"]},
    { "row": ["1", "3", "3"]}
  ]
}
```

I have a Java object like this (simplified for the example):

```
public class Item {
    String ownerId;
    String itemIdentifier;
    Integer amount:
}
```

Using Jackson would like to deserialize just the list of items into a `Collection<Item>` where the 0th item in the "row" list is the ownerId, the 1st item is the itemIdentifier and the 2nd item is the amount.

I have a deserializer that can take the the entire JSON object and map it to a `Collection<Item>`. Is there any way I can register the deserializer with an object mapper so that it is used when I deserialize to `Collection<Item>`?

Normally I would create a SimpleModule, and use addDeserializer, but it doesn't seem like this can be used to deserialize to a collection. Is there any way to register the deserializer using a TypeReference?

For example I normally would register a custom deserializer like:

```
CustomDeserializer deserializer = new CustomDeserializer();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Collection.class, deserializer);
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

But this in this cast I want to deserialize to a `Collection<Item>` where as with addDeserializer I can only specify Collection.

Additionally I am not using the object mapper directly so something like this is not an option:

```
Collection<Item> items = mapper.readValues(someJson, new TypeReference<Collection<Item>>);
```

The reason I cannot use the mapper directly I because I am using Spring's RestTemplate which uses the object mapper directly to handle deserializing a JSON request.

A final note is I would prefer not to have to wrap the items array in an outer object to get around this problem.

Comment: Have you looked into `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)` yet?  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation-Jackson-2.1-Overview#pojo-as-array